# PWA некорректно работает на ios

Tags: pwa

У меня проблема с приложением PWA на ios, при открытии и работе не основной странице все хорошо, но когда перехожу по ссылке из меню вылазит на айфонах окно от safari в приложении, как я его могу убрать? ссылку пробовал менять что при неполной "/lk/" что при полной "https://********/lk" вылазит окно[введите сюда описание изображения](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N9Ou1.jpg)

```
{
"theme_color": "#164f18",
"background_color": "#164f18",
"display": "standalone",
"capture_links": "existing-client-navigate", 
"scope": "https://vanillamarket.ru/",
"start_url": "https://vanillamarket.ru/mobile",
"name": "\u0412\u0430\u043d\u0438\u043b\u044c\u041c\u0430\u0440\u043a\u0435\u0442",
"short_name": "\u0412\u0430\u043d\u0438\u043b\u044c\u041c\u0430\u0440\u043a\u0435\u0442",
"description": "\u041e\u0444\u043e\u0440\u043c\u0438 \u0437\u0430\u043a\u0430\u0437 \u0432 \u043f\u0440\u0438\u043b\u043e\u0436\u0435\u043d\u0438\u0438!",
"icons": [
    {
        "src": "/icon-192x192.png",
        "sizes": "192x192",
        "type": "image/png"
    },
    {
        "src": "/icon-256x256.png",
        "sizes": "256x256",
        "type": "image/png"
    },
    {
        "src": "/icon-384x384.png",
        "sizes": "384x384",
        "type": "image/png"
    },
    {
        "src": "/icon-512x512.png",
        "sizes": "512x512",
        "type": "image/png"
    }
]
```

}